# getting selected text in an input field in IE8 and above

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer

How do I get the selected text in an input field in IE8 and above versions. I have tried using `window.getSelection()` `document.getSelection()` and `document.selection.createRange().text`. Last one is returning empty string and the others are undefined in IE8.

Comment: I have also tried using                                                              `input.focus();
 selected = (document.selection.createRange().text;`                                               But id doesn't help. Same empty string in fetched.

Answer (score 1):

```
var input= document.getElementById("id_of_input");
var selectedtext=input.value.substring(input.selectionStart,input.selectionEnd);
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found the solution as, `input.selection.createRange().text`.